# How do I get the touch location of a different view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, touch

Touch may specify self to get the touch location in its own coordinate system but how do i get it from another? Say another UIview's coordinate system?

```
   - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"box" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    box.center = [touch locationInView:self];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Could I but in the name of a different UIview where 'self' is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"This method returns the current location of a UITouch object in the coordinate system of the specified view", so I'd say yes, you can pass in another view. To be sure you could try with a sample project in which you have two views overlap, and NSLog the results of two calls to both views.